# AWS IoT-Lambda to check and notify on a prime number

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-iot

Being new to AWS, I have which might sound stupid but would help me to understand the functionality of the platform. I have a simple case in which I push random numbers from a Gateway device (Rasp. Pi 3) into AWS IoT. The topics which I receive there are. “message” (the random numbers) and “sequence” (sequence of the numbers).

What I am trying now is to get notification over SNS in case there exist a prime number in the incoming topic. My question/s: Do I need a Lambda function here? If yes, how it might look? A sample code (Python) would be a great help.

Is there anything else to be taken care of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [add a rule to AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html), which gets the message from the topic and in that rule add an action to call a Lambda function. Your lambda function called from IoT would look something like this:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  #event has the message from iot (parse it anyway you need)
  #use your algorithm to validate the event for a prime number

  #publish to sns
  sns_message = {"foo": "bar"}
  client = boto3.client('sns')
  response = client.publish(
    TargetArn=arn,
    Message=json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(sns_message)}),
    MessageStructure='json'
  )
```